# Changing div content with Javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use a textbox and a submit button to change a div on the page. I want to take the text that has been typed in the textbox and put it in the div when the button is clicked. I have this code:

```js
function myfunction() { 
    var myText = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = myText;
 }
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" onclick="myfunction()" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

But nothing happens. When I try it in the browser it just refreshes the page and adds `?textbox=someValueHere` to the end of the URL. How can I get the div to display the textbox value?

Comment: The snippet works as expected. What browser(s) have you tested?

Comment: If you're not altering the HTML of the div, use `textContent` over `innerHTML`. Also, you should use external event handling instead of inline.

Comment: You're not doing anything to stop the form from being submitted. `return false`?

Comment: you can also change the type from submit to button to prevent submission

Comment: I added the jQuery tag in case there's a better way with jQuery. I'm testing it in Chrome. I changed it from submit to button and now it's working. It was reloading the page right away and I wasn't noticing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the submit button is posting the form, so you are not seeing the change - If you change your submit button to a normal button it will work

```
<input type="button"name="button" id="button" onclick="myfunction()" />
```

Comment: @SterlingArcher - no, that's only if no type is defined.

Comment: @j08691 really? I thought it was any button

Comment: @SterlingArcher - if a `<button>` element has no type, then like an `<input>` with no type, it also defaults to submit. But there's no button in the question or this answer.

Comment: also I tried this and I did not get this to work properly.... **I typed something wrong**

Comment: @CayceK - Because of SO's security settings on snippets: `Blocked form submission to 'http://stacksnippets.net/js' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set.`

Comment: @j08691 thank you.. didn't see that.. I removed my incorrect answer.

Comment: Have you guys tried the above suggested code in jsfiddle? It is not working there http://jsfiddle.net/vczskf39/  , Any Reason?

Comment: make sure you javascript setting is no wrap - in head. It works

Comment: @Dashsa Suggested answer is not working in jsfiddle, any reason?

Answer (score 1):

The form is submitting. You need to stop that by adding return false; (if you are using Jquery) Or remove the form entirely it is not required.

```
function myfunction() { 
    var myText = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = myText;
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens because the form is being submitted. You need to prevent the default action from happening, which is the form submission. See `preventDefault()` or `return false` in the MDN for more details on how to prevent an events default action from occurring.

Comment: Is `return false` really in the MDN? I thought this was an old _de facto_ standard that has never been officially sanctioned. Do you have a link?

Comment: @Barmar bad wording, I meant it to preventDefault lol. I will check though

Answer (score 0):

Call `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal form submission.

```
function myfunction(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var myText = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = myText;
 } 

<form>
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" />
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" onclick="myfunction(event)" />
</form>
<br/>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```